# Acknowledge order in ebay developer API

Tags: ebay-api

I am currently build the Order Management System and try to integrate the eBay with my app.
I am reading the document of eBay seller API,
I found the API of get order list in https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/fulfillment/resources/order/methods/getOrders page, but I can not find api about the order acknowledgement.
After I get the order list, how can I acknowledge the orders?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "order acknowledgement"?

creating a listing you are automatically engaged to any order could arise, therefore there is no need to accept it.

if you mean "how do I inform eBay and the customer that the order has been processed (and shipped)" you can check
[Here](https://developer.ebay.com/api-docs/sell/fulfillment/resources/order/shipping_fulfillment/methods/createShippingFulfillment)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll read about it